# Grouping in LINQ by using ranges and calculated values

Tags: linq, grouping, range

What is the LINQ equivalent statement for the following?

```
SELECT FLOOR(Value / @Step) * @Step AS Bin,
       COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM Measurements
WHERE (StepId = @StepId)
GROUP BY Bin
ORDER BY Bin
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear where these parameters or columns are coming from but assuming LINQ to SQL, this should be more or less equivalent:

```
var step = ...;
var stepId = ...;
var query =
    from m in dc.Measurements
    where m.StepId == stepId
    group m by m.Bin into g
    orderby g.Key
    select new
    {
        Bin = Math.Floor(Value / step) * step, // where did "Value" come from?
        Cnt = g.Count(),
    };
```

Comment: value is the Measurement value returned from the Measurements table whose primary key is StepId

Answer (score 0):

with Lambda Expression :

```
var query = dc.Measurements.AsEnumerable().Where(x=>x.StepId=_stepId).
GroupBy(g=>g.Bin).Select(xg=>new
    {
        Bin = Math.Floor(Value / step) * step, 
        Cnt = xg.Count(),
    }
 );
```